# Toggle iPhone tethering by code

Tags: iphone, frameworks

I live in Canada, so am fortunate that I can tether. One issue is that to toggle tethering, you need to drill down four screens in Settings, which is just a big hassle.

A Google search returned nothing, so I was wondering if anyone here knew the code to turn on/off tethering?

I know there's a toggle for SBSettings, but I do not have a jailbroken phone, I just want to create an app I build onto my phone and have an icon for quickly toggling it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You cannot alter phone settings from within an application using any APIs allowed by the iPhone SDK. As you point out - there is an SBSettings toggle - which relies on a Private API (which you agree not to use when you get the iPhone SDK from Apple, incidentally).

Comment: Well as long as it's not an App Store app, but something I just build for myself, it should be OK no?

Comment: Yes, anything you build for yourself is OK to use private API's.

Comment: Technically - no - you agree to not use them when you get the SDK. Not that they can really enforce it for use on your own phone.

Comment: Someone has an actual answer? *bump*

Answer (score 2):

There is a file located in the Preferences folder, along with the `com.apple.SpringBoard.plist`:

```
/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.MobileInternetSharing.plist
```

In that file, you will want to set `1023` for key `State` to enable the Tethering feature. To disable the feature, you will want to set `1022` for key `State`.

**This action is only possible on a jailbroken device**