# Private API for Tethering on iPad

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios, iphone-privateapi

Is there a private API for enabling tethering in an iPad app? Since the iPhone supports tethering under some contracts, the existence of an API in the iOS is obvious…

Comment: possible duplicate of [Toggle iPhone tethering by code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440030/toggle-iphone-tethering-by-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a private tethering API.

If all you want to do is have your own private WIFI hotspot, and you're an iPhone developer, then you can download/build/install iProxy:  https://github.com/tcurdt/iProxy/wiki/.  Not quite tethering but close enough for most needs.

Answer (score 5):

There is a file located in the Preferences folder, along with the `com.apple.SpringBoard.plist`:

```
/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.MobileInternetSharing.plist
```

In that file, you will want to set `1023` for key `State` to enable the Tethering feature. To disable the feature, you will want to set `1022` for key `State`.

**This action is only possible on a jailbroken device**

Comment: Do you know, does the mobile carrier **also** need to enable tethering (via the subscriber's data plan, for example), or does calling the carrier and adding something to your plan simply change this plist value?

Comment: @WrightsCS I have jailbroken my device. Also have followed [steps to give root access to the app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841344/gaining-root-permissions-on-ios-for-nsfilemanager-jailbreak/8796556#8796556) to be able to access this file. Still I can't access it. The application gives **Permissions denied** error when in not `Applications/` folder. If I put it in `Applications/` folder then it crashes on launch.

Comment: @Yogi this was 6 years ago. Much has changed since. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @WrightsCS: Hmm..Understandable...Do you know any way in which we can accomplish this now?

Answer (score 0):

I would think anything dealing with tethering would be handled by the OS, and exposed only in the Settings app.  What sort of API functionality would you expect for that kind of OS-level feature?