# Gaining root permissions on iOS for NSFileManager (Jailbreak)

Tags: objective-c, ios, filesystems, jailbreak

I am trying to write file to the root partition of the device. It is a Jailbreak app so it is installed in /Applications. When writing to the root filesystem using `NSFileManager` the write fails with a **"Permission Denied"** error.

It seems like my app is not running as root. It is installed in /Applications though. How can my app become root?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is true, the app has to run as root to access non mobile directories. After discussing this with Optimo and Saurik I finally found the right way to get root privileges.

1. In the main() function add `setuid(0);` and `setgid(0);`
2. Build the app normally.
3. Create a copy of the executable file in the app bundle.
4. Open the original executable file and replace its content with this script:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   dir=$(dirname "$0")
   exec "${dir}"/COPIED_EXECUTABLE_NAME "$@"
   ```

   Directly launching a root app fails on iOS. Therefore we replace the app's main executable with a script that launches the root executable.
5. In terminal, navigate to the app bundle.
6. `chmod 0775` the original executable file and `chmod 6775` the copied executable file.
7. Copy the app bundle to /Applications to a device. Restart SpringBoard and you should be good to go. If the app doesn't launch then repeat step 5 & 6 on the device.

Comment: can you please guide how the step 3 onwards will take place through coding only?\

Comment: Hi,where I can find this path     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; because I cannot debug

Comment: I work on iOS 6, if I move the app bundle to /Applications it doesn't appear on the springboard :(

Comment: Fixed: I hadn't removed the old app installed via Xcode, so the springboard wasn't registering the new one with the same rfcid