# Give Cydia app root access

Tags: cydia

I am making a Cydia app that has permission to install files. I need to be able to gain root access to /Applications for this. I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052408/need-help-cydia-app-root-rights), but it was a little unclear. Could anybody explain it a little better?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out [this answer, too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8796556/119114)

Answer (score 2):

Never use system with setuid! If, for example, a malicious individual were to change the `PATH` to be `/tmp:$PATH`, and this person added their own program to /tmp and named it "ls", then even running this simple code would give them root access to your device:

```
setuid(0); system("ls");
```

Instead, you should use the exec family of functions, but not execvp/execlp.

Comment: Another way around that problem is to fully-qualify the command you pass to `system()`, like `/bin/ls` instead of just `ls`.

Comment: @Nate: not quite. `export IFS=/`

Comment: If you're claiming that `export IFS=/` will turn the `/bin/ls` command into `bin ls`, which could run a malicious script named `bin` placed somewhere in the PATH ... no, it won't. I tried it on a jailbroken iPhone. Also tried `export IFS='/'`. That's a pretty old exploit, and it looks like the jailbroken iOS shell has that fixed.

Comment: @Nate: Why are you defending the use of `system` in setuid apps? It is known to be a total failure in terms of security. I just listed two examples of why it is a bad idea. Instead of trying to find hacky, unreliable workarounds, you should be learning a more secure alternative. Now just go back to using `gets`.

Comment: The PATH example doesn't apply if you fully-quality the command, as I said.  And, I just offered feedback that I don't think the IFS exploit works, either.  If I'm wrong, and you think it still does, I'm actually interested to hear how.  But two flawed examples isn't much of a case.  And, we're talking about a jailbroken device here.  Security on jailbroken devices is already suspect, so I'm not sure why you're so worked up about this one.  Oh, and [I've already learned about using exec functions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14429668/119114), as I've mentioned in more than one of my answers.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```c
setuid( 0 ); 
system( "/path/to/script.sh" );
```

where path to script is a script in your app that would install files

or

```c
setuid( 0 ); 
system( "cmd" );
```

where cmd is a command such as

```c
setuid( 0 ); system( "echo Hello World" );
```

You can also log this way to the `/tmp` directory or any other place.

```c
setuid( 0 ); system( "echo Hello World >> /tmp/install.log" );
```

`setuid (0);` gives it root access and `system (cmd);` is the actual command

Be careful on how you use this as root has access to everywhere.