# Running shell script using Xcode with arguments on ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, shell, jailbreak

I have a bash script which I want to start with arguments by an app.
Currently I can generate the command, but how can I execute it?
This app is for jailbroken phones only.
Any solutions for this? I searched a lot, but didn't found anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a jailbreak app, you can run the command by passing it to the `system()` [function that's part of the OS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/system.3.html), or one of the `exec` functions.

So, if you decide to install your script at `/Applications/MyApp.app/myscript.sh`, then in your app, you could use:

```
int result = system("/Applications/MyApp.app/myscript.sh argument1 argument2");
```

You can install the script as I've shown, in your app's folder, as a resource, or in `/usr/bin`, or `/bin`, or wherever you like.

You don't mention whether or not you're installing your app in `/Applications`, as most jailbreak apps are, or in the normal `/var/mobile/Applications/*` locations.

If the above code doesn't work, please clarify **where** you want to install your app.  Also, depending on whether or not your script requires `root` privileges, there may be more work necessary.  There are [some complications if you want to run a shell script as root](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6503158/119114).

Comment: so, the app is installed as a normal app and in /Application/MyApp.app/ the script does not require root I tried it with system() but it didn't worked

Comment: What went wrong? `system()` returns an error code result.  What was the error code?  Did you remember to make your sh script executable with `chmod`?  Login to the phone and do an `ls -al /Applications/MyApp.app/` and let us know what the permissions look like on your script.  Thanks.

Comment: the script is downloaded from cydia, as a library and can be executed everywhere, the system returned 32512

Comment: Your first comment isn't quite clear.  If you install an app as a *normal* application, then it will **not** be in `/Applications`.  It will be under `/var/mobile/Applications`.  Which one is it?  Also, you didn't answer my question about the permissions on your script.  Is your script **executable**, after it has been deployed to your device?  Can you run it directly from the command line?

Comment: oh sorry... it is installed as a normal Application and is in /var/mobile/Applications/...
The script is in /usr/bin/ and has permissions to be executed, i can run it directly with mobile terminal (terminal emulator)

Comment: Ok, so that's the problem.  If it is installed in `/var/mobile/Applications/` as a normal app, then it's inside the normal app *sandbox*.  That means, the app cannot access (read/write/execute) files outside of that sandbox.  So, `/usr/bin` is not available.  So, the next question is "can you install your app in `/Applications/` instead"?  If not, then it's not really a true jailbreak app, even if running on a jailbroken phone. By the way, if you're developing this for other people, like Cydia users, then they will get the app installed to `/Applications`, and you should, too.

Comment: and.. how can I manage it to install to `/Applications/` instead of `/var/mobile/Applications/`

Offtopic: My App crashes on firststart when I press Run from Xcode

Comment: There's many ways to do that.  If you have terminal/shell access, you can just ssh into your device.  `cd` to `/var/mobile/Applications/` and do `find . -name MyAppName.app`.  This will find where your app is installed.  Then just copy the whole `MyAppName.app` folder to `/Applications`.  For example, after changing to the proper directory, `cp -Rp ./MyAppName.app /Applications/`.  You might then want to uninstall the original version, or else you're going to see two identical icons.  Reboot, or restart springboard, or use `su mobile -c uicache` to force springboard to see the new app.  Done.

Comment: That gets your app out of the *sandbox* that normal 3rd-party iOS apps are in.  Regarding your crash, that usually is because the app isn't properly signed, although I really don't have enough information to help with that.  You should also post a new question if you have another, separate problem.

Comment: ok, thanks, i will try to move it to `/Applications` and execute the script.

Comment: but creating a sharing folder in `/Applications` is not possible, that destroys my concept

Comment: I don't know what *creating a sharing folder in /Applications* means.  If you have additional requirements for solving your problem, they need to be posted in your question.  If you aren't willing to install your app in /Applications, it's not really a jailbreak app.