# Make command-line application for jailbroken iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

I looking for some tools to make application for jailbroken iPhone.

In my application, I need to run another application (Unix-command line with parameters).

Maybe, somebody can advice me some developer tools or libraries, because I think, that XCode is not very useful tool for these purposes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could check out [iOS Open Dev](http://iosopendev.com/)

or start reading [iphonedevwiki](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Jailbreak_Development_Tools)

but, you can certainly write apps with XCode (and maybe some scripts to postprocess your app ... fake code sign and install with `dpkg`), that issue `system()` calls.

you may need [privilege escalation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8796556/119114) depending on what you're trying to do