# iPhone - Install App To Applications Folder

Tags: iphone, sandbox

I am having issues with an app I am developing (NOTE:  It is for research/learning purposes only so it does not need to be apple store approved).  I need access to system files outside of the sandbox.  I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to install to the root /Applications/ folder to avoid being sandboxed.  From reading other questions this seems to be impossible for Xcode, but is there a way to build non-sandboxed apps with other editors?  If so, what are some?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need root permissions first and then you use the SSH feature of a jailbroken device in order to install to the /applications folder.  See here for more information that helps on this topic: [Gaining root permissions on iOS for NSFileManager (Jailbreak)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841344/error-permission-denied-when-accessing-ios-filesystem-jailbreak?rq=1)