# How to kill completely an ios root app

Tags: ios, xcode, root, jailbreak, privileges

I have created an iOS Root application for my jailbroken iPhone with this thread: [How to create root app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892795/how-to-gain-root-privileges-for-ios-app).

I can launch my app without any problems and kill it with the iOS task switcher. But I have a problem: when I want to re-open my app I can't, and this is the same for all my apps!
To debug my phone I have to reboot it :(

Here is my script to gain root privileges:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=$(dirname $0)
exec "${dir}"/rootapp "$@"
```

I think the problem is because the iOS AppSwitcher can't kill an iOS Root Application.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
# killall appname
```

where appname is the name of the running app process. You could probably make it into a shell script if you really wanted to.

Comment: Thank you but when I try to run the command "killall <myapp>". I have in the log of my device : "Kill failed. Error: Operation not permitted (1)".

Comment: This method only work when I kill the app directly (I open the multitask on my app and kill it). But when I quit my app and launch another app I can't kill it :(

Answer (score 0):

I have succeeded to do this. There is the solution to quit completely a Root Application :

In the **applicationDidEnterBackground** function just put this :

```
exit(0);
```

But thanks for your help Retr0spectrum :)