# Jailbreak app: How can I distribute my app which need to be install in /Application?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, cydia, root-access

I developed an app for jailbreak device and my **app need root access**, therefore I need to have it installed in /Application, but **I only know how to deploy it using SSH**. I find it hard for users this way.

So the question is, Is there a solution of this installation which **user just need to download and install it? And how to do it**?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I believe your question includes the answer. It's "Cydia".

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8796556/119114) and [this page, too](http://thebigboss.org/hosting-repository-cydia/submit-your-app/compile-for-cydia-submission).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a directory on your phone and inside that directory you should add all the files you want to deploy relative to the phone root directory, so like create an Applications folder to deploy those files to /Application

You also need a directory called `DEBIAN` containing your `control` file, you can get some info on what you need to put in there on Google but here's an outline of it:

```
Package: com.you.appname
Name: Your App Name
Version: 1.0
Section: Applications
Depends: (Dependancies if any)
Architecture: iphoneos-arm
Description: Your description here.
Author: You <your@email.com>
Maintainer: You <your@email.com>
```

Open mobile terminal

`cd /where/your/directory/is`

Then use `dpkg -b [directory]`

You'll be outputted a debian package (.deb) that'll install files to where they need to go on the device