# How to install deb by ObjectC code like iFile

Tags: ios, installation, jailbreak, deb, tweak

I want to install a deb of tweak by a normal app in jailbroken, so i execute this, but it doesn't work.

```
NSString *appsyncDebPath=@"/var/root/appsync.deb";
NSString *cmdString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/usr/bin/dpkg  -i %@>/tmp/dpkg.log;",appsyncDebPath];
const char  *cmdChar=[cmdString UTF8String];
system(cmdChar);
```

Is it a correct way to implement this function?

Comment: Please note the **tags** (keywords) I added to your question.  Without proper tags, nobody will find your questions.  Concerning your problem, have you tried giving your app [root privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8796556/119114)?  I know Cydia grants itself root privileges, and it does something similar (installing .deb packages).