# Gaining Root Access on Jailbroken iOS

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I've a Jailbroken iOS 5.1 and created an App, which will scan the SMS.db file. But the problem is that I cannot access the file while in Sandbox, where the application is stored.

So, what I would like to do is :

1. Install my Application in /Applications Folder. I need to know the procedure. Because I've created a simple "Hello World" app and tried to install it in /Applications but as and when I open the app, it crashes.
2. I would like to give my App the Root Permission. I've already tried the stackoverflow posts regarding the same, with no success.

Comment: It seems to be pretty well summed up here -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/8796556/1155387

Comment: Tried it already, but App crashes as and when I run it. It was the simple Hello World App, working fine from Xcode

Comment: Then you should post the crash log.  That method is the method that is used by Cydia, etc

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but I've no idea how to get the Crash Log from Cydia. But anyways, I will google for getting Crash Log and will surely put it over here for experts to judge.

Comment: You can get crash logs from xcode organizer. It doesn't matter that your app is launched from /Application folder. You should also check the console when you launch the app - some usefull info may be posted there.

Answer (score 0):

Making your app not crash is as simple as running `chmod -R 777 /Applications/<yourAppFolder>` through SSH. Let me know if that doesn't work, as there are a number of other things that could go wrong. Also, I'm pretty sure you don't have to do much else to get root access from your app, since its not in any kind of sandbox if you put it directly in /Applications