# Edit Info.plist programmatically in a jailbroken app

Tags: ios, jailbreak, cydia

How can I edit the Info.plist file in a jailbroken app I'm writing? I know it's not normally possible but given the fact that this will be released in Cydia, I feel like there must be a way. I'm not savvy on file modifications in a jailbroken environment so any info is appreciated.

The reason I want to edit the Info.plist file is to register for a URL scheme programmatically. So if there's an alternative way to accomplish that, I'd love to hear it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to programmatically edit your own app's Info.plist file as it runs, you can use this code:

```objc
- (BOOL) registerForScheme: (NSString*) scheme {
   NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Info" 
                                                         ofType:@"plist"];
   NSMutableDictionary* plist = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: plistPath];
   NSDictionary* urlType = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"com.mycompany.myscheme", @"CFBundleURLName",
                            [NSArray arrayWithObject: scheme], @"CFBundleURLSchemes",
                            nil];
   [plist setObject: [NSArray arrayWithObject: urlType] forKey: @"CFBundleURLTypes"];

   return [plist writeToFile: plistPath atomically: YES];
}
```

and if you call it like this:

```
BOOL succeeded = [self registerForScheme: @"stack"];
```

then your app can be open with URLs like this:

```
stack://overflow
```

However, if you look at the Info.plist file permissions:

```sh
-rw-r--r--  1 root wheel  1167 Oct 26 02:17 Info.plist
```

You see that you cannot **write** to that file as user `mobile`, which is how your app will run normally.  So, one way to get around this is to give your app root privileges.  [See here for how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8796556/119114).

After you use this code, and give your app root privileges, it still might be necessary to *respring* before you see your custom URL scheme recognized.  I didn't have time to test that part.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it for Facebook SDK in Swift

```
var appid: NSMutableDictionary = ["FacebookAppID": "123456789"]
var plistPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Info", ofType: "plist")
appid.writeToFile(plistPath!, atomically: true)

var appName: NSMutableDictionary = ["FacebookDisplayName": "AppName-Test"]
appName.writeToFile(plistPath!, atomically: true)

var urlStuff = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: plistPath!)
var urlType = NSDictionary(objectsAndKeys: "com.appprefix.AppName", "CFBundleURLName", NSArray(object: "fb123456789"), "CFBundleURLSchemes")
urlStuff?.setObject(NSArray(object: urlType), forKey: "CFBundleURLTypes")
urlStuff?.writeToFile(plistPath!, atomically: true)
```