# Running app on iOS 9.3.3 jailbroken with root access

Tags: ios

I am trying to give root access to my app on Jailbroken iPhone 9.3.3

I have followed the same steps as mentioned here - [Gaining root permissions on iOS for NSFileManager (Jailbreak)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841344/gaining-root-permissions-on-ios-for-nsfilemanager-jailbreak/8796556#8796556)

However the app does not gets root access. It looks like, the **setuid(0)** fails. I am using `setuid(0)` and `setgid(0)` in main function.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   if(!(setuid(0) == 0 && setgid(0) == 0)) {
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
```

The app exits in the above condition.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On your device, could you please run `stat -c '%U %a' path/to/wrapper-script /path/to/executable` and post the output here?

Comment: stat: command not found.
Do I have to look for this command in particular directory? I am hitting it from root.

Comment: My bad, you're gonna need the "Core Utilities" package from Cydia. I thought that was installed by default.

Comment: Thanks. it gives me `root 775`

Comment: for the script it gives `root 775` and for the executable it gives `root 6775`.

Answer (score 0):

> setgid(0) is not necessary

In iOS you can't run  apps as root directly you have to run them through a shell script.

Todo that:

1. Rename the app binary, for example if the binary named **App** rename it to **_App**
2. Create a text file named **App** "the name of the original binary name"
3. Inside the new created text file paste

---

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$(dirname "$0")
exec "${dir}"/_App "$@"
```