# On iOS11.4.1 jailbroken(unc0ver) device, how to run application as root?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I finally jailbroke my first device, and I want to try and run an app, built in Xcode, as root.

I tried running `setuid(0)` on my `main.c` as the first thing I do and it fails.

Also tried to run the following solution:
[[Gaining root permissions on iOS for NSFileManager (Jailbreak)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841344/gaining-root-permissions-on-ios-for-nsfilemanager-jailbreak/8796556#8796556][1])

The problem is, I can only do this manually after the app is already installed via Xcode.
In addition, I was unable, even manually, to successfully run the app this way, as it crashes on launch.

Anyone has any idea how to progress from here?

***iOS Version***: 11.4.1

***Unc0ver version***: 3.3.0

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unc0ver jailbreak exports the necessary offsets to get yourself `tfp0` (`task_for_pid(0)`) or the kernel task port. Using those, you can then patch your own credentials in the kernel memory. Let me give you an example.

Unc0ver Jailbreak stores the offsets including the `kernel task port` in a file at this path: `/var/offsets.plist`. Make sure you toggle the "Export TFP0" in Unc0ver settings before jailbreaking.

Once jailbroken, parse the offsets file, each in its own variable. 
For the `tfp0` variable, you need to make it a `task_port_t` type. The `kernel_slide` and `kernel_base` are default `uint64_t`.

Once you parsed them from the `plist`, you need to do the following to get the valid `tfp0` from `HSP4 (Host Special Port #4)` which `Unc0ver` sets for you so that you can get `tfp0` and elevate your own privileges.

Here's some sample code for that:

```
task_port_t tfp0 = null;
kern_return_t ret = host_get_special_port(mach_host_self(), HOST_LOCAL_NODE, 4, &tfp0);
    printf("Task FOR PID: 0x%x\n", tfp0);
```

This will basically get you the real kernel task port.
At this point, you can follow GeoSn0w's guide on how to elevate your own privileges to `root`, and how to escape the `sandbox`. The guide and the patches are available on his [Jailbreak Development forum](https://jailbreak.fce365.info/thread-106.html), but I will add them here just in case.

To get root privileges, according to GeoSn0w:

```
uint64_t selfProc = findOurselves();
    uint64_t creds = kernel_read64(selfProc + off_p_ucred);

    // GID
    kernel_write32(selfProc + off_p_gid, 0);
    kernel_write32(selfProc + off_p_rgid, 0);
    kernel_write32(creds + off_ucred_cr_rgid, 0);
    kernel_write32(creds + off_ucred_cr_svgid, 0);
    printf("[i] STILL HERE!!!!\n");

    // UID
    creds = kernel_read64(selfProc + off_p_ucred);
    kernel_write32(selfProc + off_p_uid, 0);
    kernel_write32(selfProc + off_p_ruid, 0);
    kernel_write32(creds + off_ucred_cr_uid, 0);
    kernel_write32(creds + off_ucred_cr_ruid, 0);
    kernel_write32(creds + off_ucred_cr_svuid, 0);
    printf("[i] Set UID = 0\n");
```

The `kernel_write32`, `kernel_write64`, `kernel_read32`, and `kernel_read64` are primitives found in `Google Project Zero` exploits usually. You will need to import them into your program so that you can call them. [They can be found on GitHub](https://github.com/googleprojectzero/ktrw/blob/master/ktrw_kext_loader/kernel/kernel_memory.c), but they are merely wrappers over the system functions such as `mach_vm_read_overwrite(...)`, and `mach_vm_write(...)`.

That's all. At that point, you should have escalated your privileges to root. Of course, you need to re-implement a lot of jailbreak functions such as the afore-mentioned kernel read and write primitives, you need the Unc0ver offsets, and you also need an offset table for things such as `off_ucred_cr_ruid`, `off_p_gid`, etc. which change from iOS version to iOS version.

It's easier to just make a tweak and have it installed by `Cydia`. `Cydia Substrate` would `rootify` it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a file inside your application bundle called e.g. `bootstrap` with the following content:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
myAppPath=$(dirname "$0")
exec "$myAppPath"/MyAppBinary "$@"
```

... where MyAppBinary is your app's binary name.

Then inside `main.m` before the UIApplicationMain call add:

```
// Set uid and gid
        if (!(setuid(0) == 0 && setgid(0) == 0))
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to gain root privileges, aborting...");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
```

Set your application's startup file to `bootstrap` instead of your binary name, and finally, upon installation either in your deb file's `postinst` or manually from a root ssh session, set the suid flag on both bootstrap and your binary, and set owner to root:

```
chown root:wheel /Applications/MyApp.app/bootstrap
chmod 6755 /Applications/MyApp.app/bootstrap
chown root:wheel /Applications/MyApp.app/MyAppBinary 
chmod 755 /Applications/MyApp.app/MyAppBinary 
uicache
```

From thereon your application should run as root, though it's not going to be as simple to update it as just a rebuild in Xcode :-)